# Prove: If there exist OWF then there exist OWF $f$ such that $ \forall x$ $f(x,x)=x$

Tags: one-way-function

I wrote the definition, but I don't know what should I do.
Can you help me?
I want to prove the following:

If there exist one-way function then there exist a one-way function $f$ such that  for every $x$ $f(x,x)=x$

Comment: That statement doesn't seem right if $f$ is a single one-way function. Are you talking about a family of functions with the first input of $f$ being the index?

Answer (score 2):

The statement is incorrect. For any function $f : \{0,1\}^{2n} \to \{0,1\}^{n}$, such that for all $x\in\{0,1\}^{n}$ it holds that $f(x,x)=x$ there exists a trivial Algorithm $\mathcal{A}$ to find a preimage.

Given $y=f(x_1,x_2)$ for random $x_1,x_2$, $\mathcal{A}$ simply outputs $(y,y)$. By definition it holds $f(y,y) = y$ and therefore $\mathcal{A}$ inverts $f$ with probability $1$.

I have the suspicion that your statement in the question is phrased incorrectly.